# how to rewind() an http stream file in PHP other than fclose() and fopen() again?

Tags: php, http, stream, fopen, fseek

PHP's fopen lets you `fopen()` http locations as file streams.
But you can't `fseek()` or `rewind()` them, is there a way to accomplish this other than `fclose()` and `fopen()` it again?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The others mentioned it: PHP doesn't support `fseek()` and `rewind()` on non-local streams. I suggest you download/cache the file and interact with that. For example

```
$cache = fopen('php://temp', 'r+');
stream_copy_to_stream($remoteResource, $cache);
```

Now you should be able to do with `$cache` whatever you have done with `$remoteResource` before, except that you are now able to seek within (and therefore also rewind) it. If you close the temp-stream PHP will automatically cleanup any used resources.

Comment: Thanks! One thing to note is `$cache` will be at the end of the stream after calling `stream_copy_to_stream` - so you might need to `rewind` it depending on what you're doing next.

Answer (score 1):

For starters, you shouldn't be using `f____` functions to open remote files. That is what curl is for.

I don't believe there is a way to reset/rewind a pointer on a remote socket, so unless PHP's file functions buffer and cache the data in the stream, I don't see how they could allow you to rewind the pointer.

I could be wrong, though...I'm no socket expert.

Comment: I don't know, maybe not `seek()` but `rewind()` could be implemented by making another call to open the stream, which is more or less what fclose();fopen() does, so it doesn't make much sense anyway.

Comment: Reopening the socket is really just closing the socket and opening a new one. It doesn't reset the pointer for the already-opened socket. New socket = new HTTP request.

Answer (score 0):

Quoting from the PHP docs

> **Note:**
>
> Not all streams support seeking. For those that do not support seeking, forward seeking from the current position is accomplished by reading and
>   discarding data; other forms of seeking will fail

As with fseek(), the rewind() function may not be used on file pointers returned by fopen() if they use the "http://" or "ftp://" formats.

Comment: Yes, that's what I said on the question.